# Why do I not get volume units from my expression?

Tags: polar-coordinates, volume

In my course we had to calculate the inner volume of a paraboloid described with $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ by converting cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.

The formula I ended up with was $f(r, \psi) = r^2$. This was then used to calculate the Volume underneath the paraboloid using:

$V =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R{r^2 *r} \operatorname{dr} \operatorname{d\psi} = \frac{2\pi}{4}[r^4]_0^R$

Now, I don't understand what happens if you plug in a value contaning a unit. I.e. if $R=2m$  wouldn't this give $V = 8\pi m^4$ ?

Comment: A paraboloid with equation $z = r^2$ means on the surface $z = r^2$ in value. In other words, the radius of cross section is $2$ unit at height $4$ unit from xy-plane. It does not mean $z$ becomes unit$^2$

Comment: The integral to find volume is $\displaystyle 2\pi \int_0^a r \left[\int_0^{r^2} dz \right] ~ dr$. So inside the integral, you have $r ~ dr ~ dz$ and so the unit is m$^3$

Comment: Your answer seems right. The issue is that $f$ is not unit consistent. There’s an implicit missing factor: $z=r^2/(1 unit)$.